# Why am I getting an invalid syntax error in my encode with Python3?

Tags: python, hash, encoding, python-3.7, cracking

I am trying to crack a set of passwords, hashes and salts, for a practice exercise. This is what I've created so far but the encode is wrong. Could anyone tell me what is wrong, I'm fairly new at this?

Thank you for the help

Below is the code

```
salt_chars = ("1", "2", "3", "a", "b", "c")
"salt".join = [random.choice(salt_chars)for salt in range(0,10)]
passwd = input("Enter your password: ")
hobj = hashlib.md5(passwd+salt)
hobj = hashlib.md5(passwd.encode() + salt.encode())
hobj.hexdigest()
with open ("spacedinosaur.txt", "w") as ucd:
    ucd.write(salt+ ":" + hobj.hexdigest)

salt = ""
pwdhash = ""
with open ("ucd.txt", "r") as udc:
    for line in udc:
        1 = line.strip()
splitln = 1,split(":")
salt = splitln[0]
pwdhash = spltln[1]
actual_hash = hashlib.md5
(passwd.encode () + salt.encode(hexdigest())
encode(hexdigest) if actual_hash == expected_hash:
 if actual_hash == expected_hash:
     print("Access granted")
 else:
     print("Access denied")
```

Comment: Yeah, the line `1 = ...` will not work because `1` is not a valid name for a varialbe

Answer (score 0):

your syntax error comes from calling encode() by itself. You need to prepend a String to call the function. `"your_string".encode()`
That should take care of your syntax error and hopefully answer your question.

Comment: Hi sorry I don't quite follow and made another error it's now hexdigest.encode() if actual_hash == expected_hash:
is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with this code.

- As others have pointed out, `1` is not a valid variable name.
- `salt.encode(hexdigest())` wont work. The argument passed to encode must be a valid encoding method like UTF-8 or ASCCI.
- You repeated `if actual_hash == expected_hash:` twice
- In python a new line is a new statement (usually) so 
  `actual_hash=hashlib.md5(passwd.encode () + salt.encode(hexdigest())` 
  and the next line have to be on the same line.
- I can't figure out what you are trying to do in this line `actual_hash=hashlib.md5(passwd.encode () + salt.encode(hexdigest())` 
  But the sytax for encode is clear `string.encode(encoding=encoding, errors=errors)`